# Does std::string const& parameter copies the passed const char*?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, c++17, implicit-conversion

sorry if this is a very noob question. I need to to know if c++ already supported the following behavior:

```
void sampleFunc(std::string const& p_sVal){
    
    Log("this is your string: " + p_sVal);

}

int main(){
    
    sampleFunc("my string");   //does the param allocates a copy of "my string"...?
    
}
```

does the param `std::string const& p_sVal` allocates a copy of the passed `const char*` or the compiler is smart enough to know that the passed is `const char*` and can be optimized that it don't need to allocate and copy?

If not, can you suggest example code that achieves this? (Note: aside for `string_view` solution.)

Comment: A common way of handling this optimization prior to string_view would be to have multiple overloads of the `sampleFunc` function. One to take `std::string const&` and one to take `const char *` so that you can handle both cases without creating an intermediate string.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary `std::string` is constructed, from the string literal you pass to it, for the `std::string const&` parameter to refer to.

As suggested in the comment, `std::string` owns its storage (otherwise it would be `std::string_view`, wouldn't it?). This observation alone, in my opinion, doesn't really tell you that the temporary `std::string` will *not* be able to steal resources from the passed argument.

The resource could be still moved, because you're passing an rvalue to `sampleFun`, right? No, wrong, because, as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), a literal string, like `"my string"` in your `main`, is a lvalue, not an rvalue.

Oh, and even if a string literal was an rvalue, from the documentation on [`std::string`'s (well, `std::basic_string`'s) constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you see that there's no other constructor taking a `&&` other then the "move constructor" (i.e. the moving version of the copy constructor, i.e. a constructor which takes the same type that it is constructing, i.e. `std::string`, not `const char*`).

Notice that since you are doing `"this is your string: " + p_sVal` you *do* want a `std::string` to be constructed at some point because you need `std::operator+` to work. You could have `sampleFunc` take by `const char*`, but then you would have to wrap either `p_sVal` or the string literal in `std::string{…}` for `+` to work.

Comment: you didn't answer the question though. can the constructed string refer internally back to the const char data already in static storage instead of copying each char, or is that disallowed, and if allowed would one typically expect compilers to do so.

Comment: The constructed string owns it's own storage, and holds a copy of the characters.

Comment: @PatrickParker, can you see if the explanation now is more thorough?

Comment: @MarshallClow thanks. that's the information that was missing from the answer.

Comment: @Enlico your analysis of the constructors notwithstanding, I believe that-- in theory at least-- a very sophisticated optimizer could recognize that the string's internal allocate+copy+deallocate was unnecessary since it could refer back to the static storage for the entire object lifetime. There is something like a "just as if" rule which allows such optimizations. However I guess in practice optimizers aren't going to do that level of code analysis. Maybe some day.

Comment: @PatrickParker, you mean that the compiler could recognize that for the call `sampleFunc("my string")`, the piece `"this is your string: " + p_sVal` can be done at compile time? (Whereas for some call `simpleFunc(some_run_time_string)` is couldn't, obviously?)